# Weak convergence in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space is equal to pointwise convergence of the sequence

Tags: solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a set, $k \colon X \times X \to \mathbb R$ be a [symmetric](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/symmetric-kernel) [positive definite kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel#Definition) and $H := \overline{\text{span}}(\{ k(x, \cdot): x \in X \})$ the induced *real* [reproducing kernel Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Definition).

> Is the followingclaim and its proof correct?

**Claim.**
Let $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset H$ and $h \in H$.
We have $h_n \xrightarrow[w]{n \to \infty} h$ ([weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Definition)) if and only if $h_n(x) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} h(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

*Proof.*
"$\implies$":
If $h_n \xrightarrow[w]{n \to \infty} h$, then $\langle h_n - h, f \rangle \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ for all $f \in H$.
Since $k(x, \cdot) \in H$, this in particular implies (this is the reproducing property of the RKHS) $\langle h_n - h, k(x, \cdot) \rangle = h_n(x) - h(x) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ for all $x \in X$.

"$\impliedby$":
Conversely, if $h_n \to h$ [pointwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence#Definition), that is, $\langle h_n - h, k(x, \cdot) \rangle \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ for all $x \in X$, then also $\langle h_n - h, f \rangle \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ for all $f \in \text{span}(\{ k(x, \cdot): x \in X \})$ by the [linearity of the inner product and by its continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Basic_properties), even for all $f \in \overline{\text{span}}(\{ k(x, \cdot): x \in X \}) = H$, which means that $h_n \to h$ weakly.

---

**Motiviation.**
A standard fact about reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces is that [strong convergence implies pointwise convergence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space). A standard fact from Functional Analysis is that [strong convergence implies weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Properties).

Comment: This looks correct to me.